# Unable to access solr admin page on server

Tags: solr

I have uploaded Solr onto a Debian server. I start it using

```
  java -jar start.jar
```

but whenever I try to access

```
 http://<server address>:8983/solr
```

I get an error

```
HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /solr. Reason:

Not Found
Powered by Jetty://
```

I have tried making a work folder inside the example folder, but that also doesn't seem to work.
I don't know what exactly is the issue.
On my local machine it works fine but I can't access the Solr admin page on the server.

Comment: resolved the issue had to add sudo before starting solr

     sudo java -jar start.jar

Answer (score 0):

Add sudo before starting solr

```
 sudo java -jar start.jar
```